# Rendering all elements at once instead of rendering boxes and waiting for images to load

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom, browser

How can I tell the browser to GET all images first and then show a ready page, instead of allowing the browser to render img elements and load the images after it?

I am using asp.net for server side, but the solution might be relevant to DOM and javascript.

I am expecting answers like 
"make a div and change the z index" or "load the images in a hidden element to start loading images earlier" or "set a header to tell browser to load images first", so this is not a question for a broad discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution would definitely have to be client side. I would suggest using jQuery. You can put all the images inside a `<div>` and set that `<div>` to invisible (i.e. `<div id="container" style="display:none">`). Then you can set an event handler for the the `.ready()` event, which shows the hidden `<div>` after the page loads:

```
.ready(function() {
  $('#container').show();
});
```